# Возможно ли программно на Си организовать цифро-аналоговый преобразователь

Tags: c, микроконтроллеры, avr

Можно ли используя восьмиразрядный микроконтроллер AVR, без встроенного ЦАП организовать его программно на Си? Суть в том, что хочется получить пилообразный сигнал!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Да это возможно. Что же для этого нужно! Первое - это применить не сложное схемотехническое решение. Схемку накидал быстро, поэтому строго не судите. Это так называемый R2R ЦАП, который позволяет превратить 8 обычных портов ввода-вывода в оди полноценный 8 битный цифро-аналоговый преобразователь. Вот схема:
[image]

Далее пишем программу которая будет генерировать Ваш пилообразный сигнал!

```
 #include <mega32.h>
    #include <delay.h>

    void main(void)
    {

    DDRA=(0<<DDA7) | (0<<DDA6) | (0<<DDA5) | (0<<DDA4) | (0<<DDA3) | (0<<DDA2) | (0<<DDA1) | (0<<DDA0);
    // State: Bit7=T Bit6=T Bit5=T Bit4=T Bit3=T Bit2=T Bit1=T Bit0=T 
    PORTA=(0<<PORTA7) | (0<<PORTA6) | (0<<PORTA5) | (0<<PORTA4) | (0<<PORTA3) | (0<<PORTA2) | (0<<PORTA1) | (0<<PORTA0);


    DDRB=(1<<DDB7) | (1<<DDB6) | (1<<DDB5) | (1<<DDB4) | (1<<DDB3) | (1<<DDB2) | (1<<DDB1) | (1<<DDB0);

    PORTB=(0<<PORTB7) | (0<<PORTB6) | (0<<PORTB5) | (0<<PORTB4) | (0<<PORTB3) | (0<<PORTB2) | (0<<PORTB1) | (0<<PORTB0);


    DDRC=(0<<DDC7) | (0<<DDC6) | (0<<DDC5) | (0<<DDC4) | (0<<DDC3) | (0<<DDC2) | (0<<DDC1) | (0<<DDC0);

    PORTC=(0<<PORTC7) | (0<<PORTC6) | (0<<PORTC5) | (0<<PORTC4) | (0<<PORTC3) | (0<<PORTC2) | (0<<PORTC1) | (0<<PORTC0);


    DDRD=(0<<DDD7) | (0<<DDD6) | (0<<DDD5) | (0<<DDD4) | (0<<DDD3) | (0<<DDD2) | (0<<DDD1) | (0<<DDD0);

    PORTD=(0<<PORTD7) | (0<<PORTD6) | (0<<PORTD5) | (0<<PORTD4) | (0<<PORTD3) | (0<<PORTD2) | (0<<PORTD1) | (0<<PORTD0);

    // Timer/Counter 0 initialization
    // Clock source: System Clock
    // Clock value: Timer 0 Stopped
    // Mode: Normal top=0xFF
    // OC0 output: Disconnected
    TCCR0=(0<<WGM00) | (0<<COM01) | (0<<COM00) | (0<<WGM01) | (0<<CS02) | (0<<CS01) | (0<<CS00);
    TCNT0=0x00;
    OCR0=0x00;


    TCCR1A=(0<<COM1A1) | (0<<COM1A0) | (0<<COM1B1) | (0<<COM1B0) | (0<<WGM11) | (0<<WGM10);
    TCCR1B=(0<<ICNC1) | (0<<ICES1) | (0<<WGM13) | (0<<WGM12) | (0<<CS12) | (0<<CS11) | (0<<CS10);
    TCNT1H=0x00;
    TCNT1L=0x00;
    ICR1H=0x00;
    ICR1L=0x00;
    OCR1AH=0x00;
    OCR1AL=0x00;
    OCR1BH=0x00;
    OCR1BL=0x00;

    ASSR=0<<AS2;
    TCCR2=(0<<PWM2) | (0<<COM21) | (0<<COM20) | (0<<CTC2) | (0<<CS22) | (0<<CS21) | (0<<CS20);
    TCNT2=0x00;
    OCR2=0x00;

    // Timer(s)/Counter(s) Interrupt(s) initialization
    TIMSK=(0<<OCIE2) | (0<<TOIE2) | (0<<TICIE1) | (0<<OCIE1A) | (0<<OCIE1B) | (0<<TOIE1) | (0<<OCIE0) | (0<<TOIE0);


    MCUCR=(0<<ISC11) | (0<<ISC10) | (0<<ISC01) | (0<<ISC00);
    MCUCSR=(0<<ISC2);


    UCSRB=(0<<RXCIE) | (0<<TXCIE) | (0<<UDRIE) | (0<<RXEN) | (0<<TXEN) | (0<<UCSZ2) | (0<<RXB8) | (0<<TXB8);

    ACSR=(1<<ACD) | (0<<ACBG) | (0<<ACO) | (0<<ACI) | (0<<ACIE) | (0<<ACIC) | (0<<ACIS1) | (0<<ACIS0);
    SFIOR=(0<<ACME);

    // ADC initialization
    // ADC disabled
    ADCSRA=(0<<ADEN) | (0<<ADSC) | (0<<ADATE) | (0<<ADIF) | (0<<ADIE) | (0<<ADPS2) | (0<<ADPS1) | (0<<ADPS0);

    SPCR=(0<<SPIE) | (0<<SPE) | (0<<DORD) | (0<<MSTR) | (0<<CPOL) | (0<<CPHA) | (0<<SPR1) | (0<<SPR0);

    TWCR=(0<<TWEA) | (0<<TWSTA) | (0<<TWSTO) | (0<<TWEN) | (0<<TWIE);

    while (1)
          {    
//Ниже код генерации такого пилообразного сигнала   
          int i;
          for(i = 0; i <255; i++) {
          PORTB = i;
          }    
          for(i = 255; i > 0; i--) {
          PORTB = i;
          }       
          }
    }
Хочу добавить , что используя R2R цап собирал wav плеер, то есть возможности очень широки. Ниже вид сигнала который я получил этой программкой.
```

93[image]93

Я даже видел как генерируют эротические сигналы, правда не знаю функцию которая за это отвечает, но можно разбить на несколько for по нарастанию и убыванию.

[image]

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать. А в чем Вы так быстро проверили?

Comment: ISIS Proteus 7.7 - удобная штука!

Comment: Вот это круто!

Comment: @vanyamelikov

    TCCR0=(0<<WGM00) | (0<<COM01) | (0<<COM00) | (0<<WGM01) | (0<<CS02) | (0<<CS01) | (0<<CS00);

Чем генерили? Руками такое написать нелегко.

Comment: Я по моему в одном из ответов указывал, что в компиляторе CodeVision AVR естьт генератор начального кода, так вот им. А сложности написать такое ручками никакой, в генераторе начального кода просто рядом с каждым параметром нужно ставить или убирать галочку, а можно взять даташит и регистры каждого параметра переписать и ставить рядом нолики или единички, главное понимать что конфигурируешь!

Comment: "Эротические сигналы". Да уж, график мощности звуковой волны говорит сам за себя.

Comment: @vanyamilikov сложность написания такого кода вручную в том, что он эквивалентен

      TCCR0 = 0;

Руками Вы ноль сдвигать никогда не будете. Так же, как и делать операцию "или" с нулём.

Comment: Да! Я же Вам так и сказал, а генератор зачем то выдает такую тягомотину! Но плюс такой сложности Вы заметите потом когда придется в силу разных изменений работать с каждым регистром в отдельности!

Comment: @vanyamelikov Генератор, он умный. Он знает, что вся эта этажерка в код не попадёт, транслятор урежет. А ему на эту тему напрягаться -- не барское дело

Answer (score 1):

Ещё один способ организации ЦАП - использование широтно-импульсного модулятора и сглаживающего фильтра (RC или LC цепочка). В этом случае напряжение ЦАПа задается коэффициентом заполнения ШИМа. Чем больше заполнение - тем больше напряжение. 
Такой подход позволяет экономить выводы микроконтроллера (один канал ЦАПа - один вывод), но не может обеспечить такую высокую частоту, как описанный [vanyamelikov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/12322/vanyamelikov) способ.
Сигналы необычной формы необязательно генерировать в процессе работы. Обычно эффективнее на этапе написания программы сгенерировать массив, состоящий из значений этого сигнала, и в процессе выполнения последовательно выдавать каждое значение на ЦАП.

Comment: В ответе на подобный вопрос, я об этом писал. Это здесь:http://hashcode.ru/questions/220999/c-как-сгенерировать-синусоиду-на-си
С ШИМ я работал, но он хорош в качестве управления системами с большой инерционностью. Низкие чатоты они сглаживают за счет еще большей постоянной времени.

Comment: И еше о работе с массивами на Си я писал здесь: http://hashcode.ru/research/219498/c-как-запустить-котел-на-си